# Error while loading a tar docker image permission denied

Tags: tar, rhel, podman

I am trying to load a tar docker image to my vm (rhel 8.4) using podman with this command.

podman image load -i /tmp/pgsql

I cannot load the image because of the error :

```
DEBU[0004] No compression detected
DEBU[0004] Using original blob without modification
Copying config 5gr88732911 done
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
DEBU[0004] Applying tar in /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/9eb82f04c782ay3f5ik25911e60d75e221ce0fe82e49f0dmmf02c81a3161d1300/diff
DEBU[0005] Error pulling image ref /tmp/pgsql: Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256: 9eb82f04c782ay3f5ik25911e60d75e221ce0fe82e49f0dmmf02c81a3161d1300": Error processing tar file(exit status 1): open /etc/group: permission denied
  **Error processing tar file(exit status 1): open /etc/group: permission denied**
DEBU[0005] Error deleting temporary directory: <nil>
DEBU[0005] parsed reference into "[overlay@/var/lib/containers/storage+/run/containers/storage:overlay.mountopt=nodev,metacopy=on]localhost/tmp/pgsql:latest"
DEBU[0005] Using blob info cache at /var/lib/containers/cache/blob-info-cache-v1.boltdb
DEBU[0005] Error pulling image ref /tmp/pgsql: Error determining manifest MIME type for dir:/tmp/pgsql: open /tmp/pgsql/manifest.json: not a directory
  open /tmp/pgsql/manifest.json: not a directory
DEBU[0005] parsed reference into "[overlay@/var/lib/containers/storage+/run/containers/storage:overlay.mountopt=nodev,metacopy=on]localhost/tmp/pgsql:latest"
DEBU[0005] Error pulling image ref /tmp/pgsql:: Error initializing source oci:/tmp/pgsql:: open /tmp/pgsql/index.json: not a directory
  open /tmp/pgsql/index.json: not a directory
Loaded image(s):
```

it seems that I cannot modify /etc/group
the vm is very hardened so we do not have the rights to write to /etc/group

I have the rights to see the /etc/group

ls -al /etc/group
-rw-r--r- root root root 1262 Apr 22 08:31 /etc/group

i've tried with another image and it isn't working

does anyone have an idea how I can resolve this ? I will be very grateful,

Thank you

Comment: What is in `/tmp/pgsql`; where did it come from?  Do you _need_ to use `docker load`, or can you use the Docker Hub `postgres` image directly (or refer to a local registry)?  Is there any source code as part of this question or is it just about loading an image on to some system, without any programming involved?

Comment: in /tmp/pgsql there is an image of pgsql downloaded previously and saved by `docker save` command  and I am not downloading it directly bcause I don't have access to the internet in the vm